# Iterating over files in a directory with Bash

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of xml files that I need to convert to json. I want to use [xml-to-json](https://github.com/sinelaw/xml-to-json) but it only accepts one file at a time. How can I iterate over every file over in the current directory and create a file with the same name.

#### calling for single file

```
xml-to-json myfile.xml > myfile.JSON
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple for loop should do the job in `bash`:

```
for f in *.xml; do
   xml-to-json "$f" > "${f%.xml}.json"
done
```

`"${f%.xml}.json"` will remove `.xml` extension and will add `.json` extension in the current xml filename.